# Hardware requirement for starters?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So im just staring to use ROS, and im building a litle robot, i just want to learn how to use ROS, and ill be using a Kinect... Just wondering what kind of CPU i need? i have a motherboard that supports 1155 Intel chips, so not sure which one to get :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107076/hardware-requirement-for-starters?/) by [SuperMiguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3779/supermiguel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2013-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I mean i currently own a very fast desktop... i7 extreme 64gb of ram, 4gb video card, raid 0 ssd, its my gaming desktop, windows OS, etc etc, i can install ubuntu and dual boot but im not sure how that would work...

---

Originally posted by [SuperMiguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3779/supermiguel/) with karma: 56 on 2013-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-06-25**:
That should be fine.